# Unable to make text box exist when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html

When i select value 6 then check box exists. When i checked the box then there should appear the text box but when i click on check box the text box is not existing. I tried jQuery and html code. Everything works perfect except existing the textbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#education').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "6") {
        $('#checkBox').show(); //text box exists
      } else {
        $('#checkBox').hide();
      }
      if ($('#checkBox').is(":checked")) {
        $("#txtData").show();
      } else {
        $("#txtData").hide();
      }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-4"><br />
               </label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8"><br />
               </label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtData" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The jQuery event handler does nothing right now, because there's  no `id="education"` element.

Comment: Its my main tab id. It works in my code. It's huge code, i am unable to post.

Comment: In that case you need to remove everything that's unrelated and post a [mcve].

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/t61nxmhw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it on my own. I got a solution. I written separate function to exist textbox.

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $('#education').on(
        'change',
        function() {

          if ($(this).val() == "6") {
            $('#checkBox').show(); //check box exists
          } else {
            $('#checkBox').hide(); //check box exists
          }


        });
    });
  
      $('#checkBox').on(
        'change',
        function() {

          if ($('#checkBox').is(":checked")) {
            $("#txtData").show();
          } else {
            $("#txtData").hide();
          }
        });
   
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need to write $(document).ready() two times. You can just attach the change event right after, the same way @ChrisG wrote it in his jsfiddle. The way you wrote it works but it may cause you trouble in the future when your code will grow. Also, you shouldn't do multiple document.ready, when you do it you ready the dom of your Navigator and you shouldn't do it multiple times unless you have a specific purpose in mind which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your textbox to appear when you change the value of the checkBox, then you need to put the event listener on the checkBox element.
I did this and it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#checkBox').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "6") {
         $('#checkBox').show(); //text box exists
      } else {
      $('#checkBox').hide();
      }
      if ($('#checkBox').is(":checked")) {
        $("#txtData").show();
      } else {
        $("#txtData").hide();
      }

    });
});
```

Here is a codepen where this works : https://codepen.io/shyrro/pen/PagvMK